# MySQL API - Store HTML tags

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form where I can also write HTML tags. I must save this textarea preserving every single HTML tag. So here's the code:

```
foreach($_POST["comment"] AS $key => $value)
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE comments SET title= '".$value["title"]."', comment = '".$value['comment']."' WHERE id = '".$value["id"]."'");
}
```

When I try to save this:

```
<b>Hello</b>
```

In MySQL I get this result:

```
&lt;b&gt;Hello&lt;/b&gt;
```

I must keep every single HTML as it is. If I write `<b>` I must save exactly `<b>` in database. I tryed escaping, html etities, quotes, strip slashes (...) but this guy keep saving everything in the wrong way.

p.s. Before you ask yes, description field is TEXT tupe with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: MySQL doesn't do that sort of encoding. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Did you try htmlspecialchars?

Comment: Why do u want the database to save <br>. It's perfectly fine to save it in tg code forms.

Comment: @Mark, htmlspecialchars encodes to html entities, you need the opposite in this case I believe.

Comment: What about `mysql_real_escape_string()` in conjunction with some of the things you've already tried? Or is that what you meant by "escaping"? In a test I ran, it did enter `<b>Hello</b>` in my DB using `stripslashes()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` only, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php on the mentioned value? This should do exactly what you're asking.

try running:

`$sStr = '&lt;b&gt;Hello&lt;/b&gt;';
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($sStr);`

And it will be encoded properly. Feeding that to the database stores the value correct.

Also, but this is more of a side-notice, you really shouldn't save post data without validating the input. I do assume this is just a quick example and not production code? However, just a suggestion.

Comment: Yes! It's the solution. I needed the opposite of htmlspecialchars like you stated in another message. Thank you.

Comment: You are quite welcome. For future reference, please do note the root cause. All posted data will be urlencoded which explains what you ran into in the first place. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape the entry. If you are using the mysql method, you need the mysql_escape_string function like:

```
$string = mysql_escape_string("<br>Hello</br>");
```

Comment: As mentioned by Mike, mysql_real_escape_string does not convert html entities back to utf characters. It only adds escaping chars. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php